# I am getting different number when I post (send) uuid to the server using android retrofit2

Tags: php, android, mysql, retrofit2, uuid

When I send UUID with android retrofit using post and store it to MySQL database I am getting different value, it is shorten and converted to numbers.
Is there anything I have to do when I receive the UUID in PHP or when I store it to MySQL database table?

This is the UUID generated in my android application:

7cbb95ec-2de6-42a4-bd54-5a18b392ca03

and when it is stored into the user table it become like this numbers:

795-26-424-54-51839203

Please can someone explain why this happening and how to fix?

Api interface

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("insertdata.php")
Call<ResponseBody>insertdata(
    @Field("userid")String userid,
    @Field("articleid")int articleid);
```

Php insertdata.php

```
if (isset($_POST['userid'])) {
    $userid = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'userid', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
} else {
    die();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a numerical value, so don't filter it like it is. You're deleting the non-numerical characters. Don't `filter_input`, just leave it alone.

For SQL injection issues, as always, **use prepared statements with placeholder values**.

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely right, that resolve the issue.  I notice that after I posted the question. I have tested it and it works.